# Как разместить свою службу WCF на Хостинге?

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, wcf

Я сделала небольшое приложение , просто складываю числа, но считаются они на сервере. При подключении службы в приложении указываю локальный адрес моей службы. `http://localhost:60289/Service.svc` все подключается и работает
[Вот тут пример создание сервиса, по котормоу я делала.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-wcf-service-in-windows-forms?view=vs-2019&tabs=csharp)
Но я не могу разобраться как залить свой сервис на бесплатный хостинг. Точно знаю что для этого требуются следующие файлы

`Service.svc`

`Web.config`

`Web.Debug.config`

`Service.cs`

[Вот тут есть бесплатный хостинг.](https://cp.sprinthost.ru)
Если туда поместить файлы index.php то этот файл, как и принято везде запустится, а точнее отобразить веб страницу, а вот если обратиться к моим файлам, то они просто начинают скачиваться.

Comment: Так C# проект это не PHP, почему вы думаете, что они должны просто так запустится?)  WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) - это старая технология, которая написана для Windows, а значит и хостинг вам нужен [с Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/hosting-services), на которой сможете установить либо IIS, либо запустить службу. PHP хостинги, это обычно Linux системы, где дается минимальный набор ресурсов, чтоб запустить простые сайты визитки. Если вы хотите написать что-либо под Linux, то вам нужны другие инструменты, кроссплатформенные, современный .NET такое умеет.

Comment: WCF - это что-то древнее, и только для Windows

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да это удалось вычитать, но я не могу найти таких хостингов, банально не понимаю как искать, белого ip у меня то же нет , поэтому приходится искать хостинг и как его туда выгружать то же не понятно в интернете нет каких то примитивных примеров

Comment: @aepot, это для лабы

Comment: Берите любой платный хостинг с Windows, и готово. Можете у автора лабы узнать подробности, как он это себе представляет.

Comment: А не существует бесплатных хостингов с Windows. Windows требует много ресурсов, которые просто так вам не будут давать. Хотите старый WCF на хостинг - придется раскошелится (погуглите `VPS/VDS Windows`), ну а если хотите на таком хостинге что либо запустить, то вам нужен проект, который запустится под Linux, а точнее под Nginx (почти все PHP на нем), а это уже допустим ASP.NET, через который можете сделать либо простой API, либо нечто на подобии gRPC, SignalR и др. И то, простой хостинг не даст вам запустить, ибо нужна настройка nginx под запуск .NET, тут нужен VPS/VDS Linux.

Comment: Бесплатный хостинг с Windows всё же есть. По крайней мере, триальный. Например, [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/)

Comment: WCF так и не умер. Более того, получил второе дыхание. [WCF Client Libraries](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf), [CoreWCF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/) - современные реализации для .NET Core. Вам нужна CoreWCF для реализации службы. Её сможете хостить и на Linux.